# Convert canvas into image data in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

currently, I am working on a react-native project and my requirement is to draw some image ,Text,widgets on a canvas and then convert this canvas to Image Type Data(JPEG/PNG) or Base64 data so that we can render it into  view.

my code snippet for rendering on canvas is -

```
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.arc(50, 50, 49, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
```

[image: ScreenShot of mobile in which yellw part is canvas]

now i want to get convert this canvas into image type data(JPEG/PNG/BASE64)

code snippet

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
        .then((data) => {
            data = data.substring(1);
            data = data.slice(0, -1);

            if (data.indexOf('data:image/jpeg;base64,') > -1) {
                // Removing "data:image/jpeg;base64," for saving into file as base64 data
                data = data.substring(23);
            }

            RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/atar.png", data, 'base64')
                .then((data) => {
                    // Image data saved and has 200x4 pixels width and 300x2 pixels height
                })
        })
```

this code successfully creating .png file.but the image size is totally different from canvas size(300 * 300).

[image: output image]

my requirment is create the image of same resolution as of canvas.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

please, check yours CSS canvas div/View size.
it must be the same as canvas tag sizes